# Want a regular expression script which will only find a varaible followed by '='; but not '=='

Tags: shell, grep

Example:

I want to grep for "variable.*="

But I also get results as:

"variable =="

So, how can grep only for variable followed by equal to sign('=') but not the "equality check operator" ('==').

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit of overkill, but you can use `grep -P '.*(?<!=)=(?!=).*'`.
It will match `variable=x`, but not `variable==x`. It uses negative lookbehind and lookahead to achieve this.

Comment: I just noticed the -P is not available on FreeBSD, just for info ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're not expecting `variable =` at the end of a line, then the regex below will do what you want.  It's `=` followed by `[^=]` (i.e. anything that is not `=`).

I've used `<space>*` to skip spaces.  You were using `.*` which will skip anything, so you'll match `variable2 =` for example.

Alternatively you could use `\s` to skip all whitespace, but I think that just skipping spaces is probably what you want in this case.

```
grep 'variable *=[^=]'
```

Comment: I tried to come up with something and came up with this `grep 'variable[^=]*=$\|variable[^=]*=[^=]'` , just to make sure for this one special case where `variable[^=]*=` is at the end.

Comment: To handle `variable =` at the end of the line, you can use "extended" regexes with grep and use a `$` to indicate the end of line: `grep -E 'variable *=([^=]|$)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'variable[^=]*=$\|variable[^=]*=[^=]'
```